# How do I get list of nodes from calculated shortest path?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

My Cypher looks like this:

```
START source=node(16822), target=node(12449)
MATCH p = allShortestPaths(source-[*]-target)
return p
```

And I want to write equivalent C# code for this. This is what I've come up till now

```
var query = client.Cypher
.Start(new { source = sourceNode.Reference, target = targetNode.Reference })
.Match("p = allShortestPaths(source-[*]-target)")
.Return<Node<Data>>("x");
```

Where Data is the class which has a string property(string ID).

What should i put in place of x to get my result as a list of concatenated IDs which comprises the path.

Comment: In you cypher query, can you try this one `START source=node(16822), target=node(12449)
MATCH p = allShortestPaths(source-[r]-target)
return source,r,target`

Comment: no, it throws exception, it expect x to be of type Node<Data>. I want it to be of type IEnumerable<Data> which represents the nodes which comprises the paths

Answer (score 1):

Cypher 2.0

```
 START source=node(16822), target=node(12449)
 MATCH p = allShortestPaths(source-[*]-target)
 return nodes(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old way of executing query was the last resort which i used

```
CypherQuery query1 = new CypherQuery(@"START m=node(" + sourceNode.Reference.Id.ToString() + "),     n=node(" + targetNode.Reference.Id.ToString() + @")                                                   
                                                match p = allshortestpaths(m-[*]-n)
                                                return distinct Extract(x in NODES(p): x.NodeId) as paths", paramCollection, CypherResultMode.Set);
            var paths = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<List<string>>(query1);
```